# In Javascript, in json array, between filter and for loop, which one will have better performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

My code is to get list of users that belong to group "A" (user can belong to many group).
I have 2 ways to filter data as below.

Method 1:

```
let data = userList.filter(u => u.group.filter(g => g === "A").length > 0)
```

Method 2:

```
let data = []
for(let n = 0; n < userList.length; n++){
    let u = userList[n]
    if(u.group.filter(g => g === "A").length > 0){
        data.push(user);
    }
}
```

I wonder which one above will have better performance in case "userList" contains a lot of data?

UPDATE: Fix incorrect code.

Comment: This could depend on a lot of factors, including which javascript engine, computer and shape of the data. If you're worried this matters, just test it yourself.

Comment: Your second approach won't work, because you have two `filter` instead of only one. Other than that, a definitive answer can only be given after testing with your own data in your own environment. But unless you have millions of iusers, once you fix the error, you probably won't find any significant difference

Comment: If you really notice any performance issues, you should probably think about other data structures. For instance an index for your groups ...

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks, I have corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

#### I predict the first will be more performant

It is also easier to understand, which is important since quite often we spend more time staring at the code, than the code will spend running.

#### You can speed it up by stopping the inner search as soon as we find one match

You could change the `.filter().length>0` to `.some()`

```
let data = userList.filter(u => u.group.some(g => g === "A"))
```

#### But since you are comparing each element of an array with a string, you can be even faster:

```
let data = userList.filter(u => u.group.includes("A"))
```

Comment: You are right about avoiding the "inner" `filter` and readability and maintainability. But 1) Why would you predict the first one is more performant? I assume unless there are millions of elements in the array it won't make significant difference, but the second one will be slightly faster because calling an additional function (ie the callback of filter) millions of times might be expensive (because the execution stack is involved)

Comment: 2) have you actually tried your first suggestion? `u.group.some(g => g === "A").length > 0` does not make any sense, because `some()` returns a `boolean`, and `boolean`s don't have a `length` property. So your comparision is actually `userlist.filter(u => undefined > 0)`, which makes absolutely no sense (and it will return `false` and therefore `data` will just be an empty array)

Comment: And finally, if performance is really an issue, OP should think about a datastructure that better fits the needs Ie something like `{"A": ["u1", "u2"] }` this way, finding all users for group "A" ist just a simple lookup (assuming there are far less groups than users)

Comment: @derpirscher presumably the index approach is only beneficial if you get to re-use it or get it in some way for free (in terms of the currently running operation)?

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a crude way that you could test it. Things like the actual nature of your data and the environment might have a significant impact on the results.

```js
const rando = () => (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);

let userList = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
  userList.push({ name: rando() + rando(), group: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].filter(() => Math.random() > 0.5) });
}

const crude_perf_test = (fn, times = 1000) => {
  let total_time = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < times + 1; i++) {
    let start = performance.now();
    fn();
    total_time += performance.now() - start;
  }
  return total_time / times;
};

const fn_A = () =>
  userList.filter(u => u.group.filter(g => g === "A").length > 0);

const fn_B = () =>
  userList.filter(u => u.group.some(g => g === "A"));

const fn_C = () =>
  userList.filter(u => u.group.includes("A"));

const fn_D = () => {
  let data = [];
  for(let n = 0; n < userList.length; n++) {
      let u = userList[n];
      if(u.group.filter(g => g === "A").length > 0){
          data.push(u);
      }
  }
};

const fn_E = () => {
  let data = [];
  for(let n = 0; n < userList.length; n++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < userList[n].group.length; i++) {
      if(userList[n].group[i] === 'A') {
        data.push(userList[n]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};

[fn_A, fn_B, fn_C, fn_D, fn_E]
  .map( (fn) => [fn.name, crude_perf_test(fn)] )
  .sort( (a, b) => a[1] - b[1] )
  .forEach( ([name, result]) => console.log(name, result) );
```